# Form Load/Unload Event Not Triggered After Importing Form in Access 2007

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

So I just manually split a database following the steps found [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932/). For some reason the load event is not triggered on one form and on another the unload event is not triggered (but in each case, the opposite one does work). The second form (Unload not working) also refuses to go into design mode until I close it manually and then open it into design mode. I have confirmed that the open and close events are linked properly to their corresponding VBA code so I know that isn't it.

Any help with resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Edit-

Here is the code for the Load:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim scr As ScriptControl
    Dim SQL As String

    CheckConnection
    Set scr = New ScriptControl
    SQL = "UPDATE [Part Number] SET [Part Number].[Select] = False WHERE ((([Part Number].[Select])=True));"
    CurrentDb.Execute SQL

    scr.Language = "VBScript"
    scr.AddCode "Sub T :Dim ChangeReg: Set ChangeReg = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell""):ChangeReg.regwrite " & _
                """HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\VBAWarnings"", ""1"", ""REG_DWORD"" : " & _
                "Set ChangeReg = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell""):ChangeReg.regwrite " & _
                """HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security\VBAWarnings"", ""1"", ""REG_DWORD"": end sub"
    scr.Run "T"

    Locked = False
    CancelBupdate = False
    LockOff

    USRID = Environ("Username")

    TTTCount = 0
    Started = True

    SourceSelect.Value = 1

    DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , True
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
    DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo

    ChgFrmOpen = False
    Me.LocationSelect.Visible = False
    Me.ClrSupLoc.Visible = False
    Me.Label20.Visible = False
    PSOn = True

    Me.RepSelect.Value = ""
    Me.SupplierSelect.Value = ""
    Me.SupNumSelect.Value = ""
    Me.LocationSelect.Value = ""
    Me.Base5Select.Value = ""
    Me.FullNbrSelect.Value = ""
    Me.Label104.Caption = "Last Updated On: " & DLookup("[Last Updated]", "[Last Updated]")
    ChangeCount = 0
    CT = ""
    CPP = ""
    PGNP = ""

    UpdateSub '****
    InfoGet
    RunFilter
    Cascade
    Me.Requery

    Select Case USRID
        Case "vn034153"
            UsrInfoSt = "Logged in as User"
        Case "vn043156"
            UsrInfoSt = "Logged in as User"
            Blah
        Case "vn034157"
            UsrInfoSt = "Logged in as Admin"
            Me.UpdateButton.Visible = True
        Case "vn034160"
            UsrInfoSt = "Logged in as User"
        Case "vn028040"
            UsrInfoSt = "Logged in as User"
        Case "vn028033"
            UsrInfoSt = "Logged in as Admin"
            Me.UpdateButton.Visible = True
        Case "vn034931"
            UsrInfoSt = "Logged in as User"
        Case Else
            UsrInfoSt = "Logged in as User"
    End Select

    Me.UsrInfo.Caption = UsrInfoSt
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Action Queries", 0
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Document Deletions", 0
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", 0
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Application.SetOption "Auto compact", True
End Sub
```

And here is the code for the unload (using a cmd button and neither sub runs):

```
Private Sub OpenDatabase_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "2BHPartsDatabaseX"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim TDF As TableDef
    Dim QDF As QueryDef
    Dim DBS As Database

    Set DBS = CurrentDb()

    Me.ReportForm.SourceObject = ""

    For Each QDF In DBS.QueryDefs
        If QDF.Name = "TempQRYX" Or QDF.Name = "DistinctPGNQry" Then
            DBS.QueryDefs.Delete QDF.Name
        End If
    Next

    For Each TDF In DBS.TableDefs
        If TDF.Name = "ProjectTable" Then
            DBS.TableDefs.Delete TDF.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Application.SetOption "Confirm Action Queries", 1
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Document Deletions", 1
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", 1
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: When you go into the Form properties, under events, does it say `[Event Procedure]` in the appropriate events?

Comment: Yes, and clicking the ellipses takes me to the proper section of code.

Comment: Okay. Well..... there's not much more we can do without seeing the code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would comment (rem) out all the code in the Form_Load Event, and put a breakpoint on the 
Sub procedure, then open the form to see if the event fires.  After I see it fire,
I would begin to "un-rem" each line until the code line affecting the load event
is found.

I would do the same with the "Unload" issue.

Comment: I would have thought that not having a reference made would throw an error but I guess not... I did not have the proper references set up in the new database to use `scr As ScriptControl` so it was just ignoring the whole sub.